# Perl - windows to libux

Tags: windows, perl, linux

У меня есть жизненно важный скрипт, но он работает только под Windows. Немного поломав голову, я понял, что проблема взаимодействия с системой, и все рушится из-за 2-х строк. Можете помочь мне их исправить пожалуйста... Очень вас прошу.

У меня на перле скрипт лежит в папке с фото. Работает отменно. Но есть второй скрипт, который лежит в той же папке и выполняет скрипт №1.

Вот здесь есть скрипт: [плавная смена кадров в timelapse/slideshow видео](http://ru-timelapse.livejournal.com/35503.html). Я так понял, проблема в строках с №35 по №46.

```
my $cmd = "smooth.pl --fps $fps --start-image $start_img --final-image $final_img --progression $progression";

# To consume all available CPU cores without slowing down the system  
# meke each 8-th smooth.pl running in foreground  
# while other 7 smooth.pl scripts are running in background.  
# These lines needs to be rewritten to run under Linux.

if ($i % $threads_num) {  
     print BATCH "START /MIN /BELOWNORMAL CMD /C CALL $cmd\n"  
} else {  
    print BATCH "$cmd\n"  
}
```

Я пробовал выполнить скрипт без изменения. Результат:

```
composing batch file './smooth_all.bat'... done.
```

Помогите, пожалуйста. Очень нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, что отформатировали

Comment: Вы очень сумбурно описали проблему. Что именно очень нужно, запустить под linux? 

Comment: Да, я линуксоид

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение в лоб, без всяких тредов: заменить строки

```
if ($i % $threads_num) {  
     print BATCH "START /MIN /BELOWNORMAL CMD /C CALL $cmd\n"  
} else {  
    print BATCH "$cmd\n"  
}
```

На

```
system $cmd;
```

Comment: Во-первых перед smooth.pl в $cmd нужно поставить `perl `

Во-вторых здесь сделано так, чтобы 7 команд выполнялись асинхронно.

Было бы все так просто, я бы и не спрашивал

Comment: В таком случае, форкайте по очереди: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html

Answer (score 0):

Вообще в Perl есть такой элемент как $^O (Буква "О", не ноль). Эта переменная хранит в себе информацию о системе, где запущен интерпретатор. Так что в принципе просто делаешь:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
if ($^O eq 'MSWin32') 
{
Блок
} else
{
Блок
}
```

Ну вот что то типа такого.... Это сделает скрипт переносимым с одной платформы а другую.