# Перебор файлов по порядку

Tags: массивы, perl

В [предыдущем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/139356/linux-perl-windows-to-libux) мне нужно было перевести один скипт из линукса в виндовс.

В windows по ходу он должен работать нормально, но у меня возникла новая проблема.
Файлы в этом скрипте перебираются не по порядку. То есть он может взять сначала 25-й файл + 80-й, потом 80-й + 37-й. Я мылил свой мозг, и так и не понял, откуда такой порядок, но он есть. Печально.

Я perl не знаю (хотя с другими языками знаком), а из-за одного скрипта учить язык и лезть в дебри у меня нет времени.

В [этом скрипте](http://ru-timelapse.livejournal.com/35503.html) в строках №25 - №27 открытие папки (25), чтение содержимого и отсев нужных файлов и создание массива $image_files (26), проверка на количество (27).

```
opendir(DIR, $directory) || die "ERROR: cannot open dir '$directory'\n";  
 my @image_files = grep{ /$filter/i } readdir(DIR);  
 ( $#image_files > 2 )    || die "ERROR: at least 2 images required\n";
```

Классно. Жаль только не работает как надо.

Пожалуйста, помогите по-сортировать массив в порядке возрастания, учитывая то, что перед названием файла идет какой-то префикс (например "IMG_", или "DSMC"), потом идет число и во всех этих числах одинаковое количество символов. Пример списка файлов:

- IMG_1639.JPG
- IMG_1640.JPG
- IMG_1641.JPG
- Типо здесь еще куча файлов
- IMG_2154.JPG
- IMG_2155.JPG
- IMG_2156.JPG

Или

- DSCN02806.JPG
- DSCN02807.JPG
- Типо здесь еще куча файлов
- DSCN03256.JPG
- DSCN03257.JPG

Пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Камрад [@Asid](/users/4900/asid) частично прав. Нужно применить функцию sort. И хотя проблема не в том, что perl хранит элементы массива в каком-то своём порядке, она должна помочь. На самом деле, он хранит их в том порядке, в котором они были добавлены в массив. А перепутаны они скорее всего потому, что таким возвращает список функция readdir, которая не гарантирует алфавитный порядок.

```
my @image_files = sort grep { /$filter/i } readdir(DIR);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl хранит элементы массива в своем, одному ему ведомом порядке. И выводит их соответственно. Попробуй применить перед  распечаткой функцию "sort", для их сортировки.